# Where to get AdventureWorks2008R2 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have searched lot about AdventureWorks2008R2 database, but couldn't get proper URL.

Can anybody please tell the location (URL) where can I download from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926

EDIT

As you can see in the comments of this download page, maybe there are some problem with the download process. I also tried it, and the first time it didn't run. The file may seem to be complete but it is not. Try to download one more time until you get the exact size of 86302720 bytes. (Nov 17 2010, Stable version)

Comment: I have already tried this link, but downloaded file is corrupted, I guess. It is giving the message like
C:\Ashok\Downloads\SQL Server 2008 R2 Databases\AdventureWorks2008R2_SR1.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: What OS do you use? Did the download complete successfully?

Comment: I am using Windows XP. Download was completed successfully. I am getting the error when I double click on the file to install.

Comment: Link had no files. try this: [link](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/105902)

Answer (score 0):

The above link now lands at a redirect page.

The updated location is now on GitHub at:
https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks